# Redirect All Search Links Containing - to + on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, search, tags

I deleted all my wordpress **tags** via **phpmyadmin**, and most of my post content contains **tag links**, now I redirected all the **tag links** to **search** using .htaccess,

I.E

`example.com/tag/stack-over-flow/` will be redirected to `example.com/search/stack-over-flow/`

It worked fine on some links, but I notice that some of the links does not pull out post title due to the `-` sign on the search link url, If i replace the `-` with `+` it will find my post content (title), but if it is `-` sign on the link url its does not pull out my post content when it is searched.

Please I there any way I can redirect all the search urls containing `-` on the link url to `+`

I.e redirecting `example.com/search/stack-over-flow/` to `example.com/search/stack+over+flow/`

`.htaccess` is preferable.